# External Control of System or Configuration Setting (CWE ID 15)

Tags: c#, connection-string, veracode, database-connection, secure-coding

We had security threat issue when scanning applications in Veracode. Got "External Control of System or Configuration Setting (CWE ID 15)".

Scan reported for  `using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))`

we are checking whether **"SQLConnectionExists"** by passing connection string,

```
string sqlConnString = SqlHelper.GetSQLConnectionString(input.ServerName, dbName, isWinAuth, input.UserName, input.Password);
if (!DBUtil.CheckSQLConnectionExists(sqlConnString))
{
_ValidationMessage += "Database Unreachable \n";
isValid = false;
}

public static bool CheckSQLConnectionExists(string connectionString)
        {
            bool isExist = false;
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    connection.Close();
                    isExist = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Instance.Log(LogLevel.EXCEPTION, "CheckSQLConnectionExists Exception : " + ex.Message);
            }
            return isExist;
        }

public static string GetSQLConnectionString(string servername, string db, bool isWinAuth, string username, string password)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder["Data Source"] = servername;
            builder["Initial Catalog"] = db;

            if (isWinAuth)
            {
                builder["Integrated Security"] = "SSPI";
                builder["Trusted_Connection"] = "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                builder["Persist Security Info"] = false;
                builder["User ID"] = username;
                builder["Password"] = password;
            }

            return builder.ConnectionString;
        }
```

In this line `using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))` we got error in security scan. Could you please some one provide suggestions to resolve this Veracode error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veracode detects input.ServerName, input.UserName and input.Password to be user-controlled which is a risk.

Ensure validation is implemented - if possible, compare against a whitelist or known predefined server names. Also, check if the entered (injected) Min Pool Size is larger than expected. Use framework classes such as the one that you used SqlConnectionStringBuilder

Propose this check as a [mitigation](https://help.veracode.com/reader/DGHxSJy3Gn3gtuSIN2jkRQ/%7Ep4MSKOS8F8X8h0KwFTKoQ) afterwards.

Comment: The input.servername, input.UserName and input.Password values are not in our hand. These values will be changed based on the customer choice, we can't predict the pattern exactly. so any other possibilities?

Comment: Some SAST platforms would consider the SqlConnectionStringBuilder as a safe way to dynamically construct the connection string at runtime. I would consider this as a false positive if predefined connection strings isn't possible. I've updated my answer to include some additional recommendation

Comment: as you mentioned it is marked as "false positive",because we used  SqlConnectionStringBuilder to get connectionstring which will not allow connection string injections.